# Grouping doesn´t work in linq to sql. How is the correct sintax to do it

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, informix

When i try to group rows from the context, an exception is generated, but when i do exactly the same grouping in a list, works perfectly.  How can this happen.  I'm using an informix database.

this works perfeclty: (load rows into list, then make grouping)

```
 var listaCentros = (from cen in context.CenopeMaes select cen).ToList();
 var listaTipo = (from tc in listaCentros
                  group tc by tc.CenTipo into grupo
                  select new {
                      Tipo = grupo.Key,
                      Total = grupo.Count()
                  });
```

this throws an exception :  make grouping directly from context.

```
var listaTipo2 = (from tc in context.CenopeMaes
                             group tc by tc.CenTipo into grupo
                             select new
                             {
                                 Tipo = grupo.Key,
                                 Total = grupo.Count()
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: "an exception is generated" - what does the exception *say*?

Comment: @Dortimer pretty sure you can... whether this is supported by the informix SQL generator, however, is another question; also, this is EF-Core, not LINQ-to-SQL (but you should still be able to group in most cases)

Comment: To me it also looks like you are working in 2 different tables, in the first example you first take all records from "cen" on which you then later do your second query. In the second example you do not do this query on "cen", can it be that you are missing an JOIN?

Comment: the exception message is : ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] The column (tipo) must be in the GROUP BY list.

Comment: and the sql generated is : SELECT tc.CenTipo AS Tipo, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM cenope_maes AS tc  . Obviously doesn't have the "group by" sentence

Comment: @MarioRamos sounds like a bug in the SQL generator for informix, then...